# Fixed time step with Akihabara

Tags: 2d, algorithm

How could I implement fixed time step with [Akihabara framework](http://www.kesiev.com/akihabara/)? I would like my avatar to move by fixed distances of one block as in [Supaplex](http://www.elmerproductions.com/sp/).

Comment: This question seems kind of broad. You're basically asking "how do I do X with this?" As with anything, there's a bunch of ways you could go about it. I'm not familiar with the framework but since it's written in Javascript you could probably just wrap your main game loop in a `setTimeout` type function.